# SQL Server: Case expression returns NULL even with an ELSE

Tags: sql-server, case

Does anyone know why this case expression would be returning NULLs even when there is an ELSE?  It returns 'Normal' and 'Premature', but also numerous NULLs.

```
   select distinct(external_id), encounter_date,
(select             
 case               
   when h2.encounter_date < DATEADD(WEEK, -3, isnull(f2.edd_final_date,'01-jan-1900')) 
      and h.encounter_date < DATEADD(dd, 29, isnull(t2.date_value,'01-jan-1900')) 
     then 'Premature-Emergency'
   when h2.encounter_date < DATEADD(WEEK, -3, isnull(f2.edd_final_date,'01-jan-1900')) 
     then 'Premature'
   when h.encounter_date < DATEADD(dd, 29, isnull(t2.date_value,'01-jan-1900'))  
     then 'Emergency'
   else 'Normal'
 end 
 from enhfile h2              
inner join ar00file a2 on a2.patient_no=h2.patient_no and a2.trans_date=h2.encounter_date
      inner join endfile d2 on d2.patient_no=h2.patient_no and d2.encounter_no=h2.encounter_no
         and d2.charge_no=a2.charge_no
      left join fmhfile f2 on f2.patient_no = h2.patient_no          
      left join notesdtl t2 on t2.patient_no=n.patient_no and t2.note_id=n.note_id
          and element_id in ('4559','4560')  
 where h2.patient_no=a.patient_no and h2.encounter_date= 
     (select MaxEncDate
      from (select MAX(h4.encounter_date) as MaxEncDate from enhfile h4
              inner join ENDFILE d4 on h4.PATIENT_NO=d4.patient_no and h4.ENCOUNTER_NO=d4.encounter_no
            where h4.patient_no=h2.patient_no
              and a2.procedure_code in ('59409','59410','59400','59514','59515','59510','59415') 
           ) v
     )
  and f2.history_date=(select MaxHxDate
                            from (select MAX(f3.history_date) as MaxHxDate from fmhfile f3
                                  where f3.patient_no=h2.patient_no 
                                 ) w
                      )                  
  group by h2.patient_no, h2.encounter_no, t2.date_value, h2.encounter_date, f2.edd_final_date)
  as Circumstance
from ar00file a
inner join mpfile m on m.patient_no=a.patient_no
inner join exidfile x on m.patient_no=x.patient_no
inner join chhfile c on a.procedure_code=c.procedure_code
inner join enhfile h on a.patient_no=h.patient_no and  a.trans_date=h.encounter_date
inner join endfile d on h.patient_no=d.patient_no and h.encounter_no=d.encounter_no 
left join fmhfile f on f.patient_no=h.patient_no 
left join noteshdr n on n.patient_no=h.patient_no and n.note_date_time=h.encounter_date
          and n.note_type='FSP'
left join notesdtl t on t.patient_no=n.patient_no and t.note_id=n.note_id
          and element_id in ('4559','4560')  
where d.charge_no=a.charge_no
and a.trans_date between '01-jan-2016' and '30-jun-2016'  
and a.PROCEDURE_CODE in ('58600','58611','58670','58671','58150','58150GY','58180GY','59525')
```

Comment: Still the query not complete. But: if the query after "encounter_date" (the subquery) match no records, you will have nulls in your result set.

Answer (score 1):

I would try adding some ISNULL functions to the left sides of the Case checks (h.encounter_date and h2.encounter_date), as I don't see a WHERE h.encounter_date/h2.encounter_date IS NOT NULL in your WHERE clause.